# Selecting a value from a p tag within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am creating a list of records that is contained within divs, I want to get the value of the contents within a p tag that is within the div clicked. How do I reference to the p tag and its value with a .click function, using some jquery?

What I have

```
<div class="result_box">
     <p class="result_text" id="res_id">id# 0000000</p>
     <p class="result_text" id="res_mail">resume@resume.com</p>
     <p class="result_text" id="res_complete">Active</p>
     <p class="result_text" id="res_date">11/11/11</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var record       = $(".result_box"); //Fields wrapper

 $(record).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    //e.preventDefault();
    var record_id = //whatever value is within <p id="res_id">

    alert('button_clicked');
});
```

Additional info if needed, the class "result_box" is the same throughout, but I just want the value with that specific result box.

Comment: fyi id's have to be unique.

Comment: @DanielA.White his Ids are unique, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `div` clicked, use:-

```
var record_id = $(this).children('#res_id').text();
```

Though, as an Id should be unique, you could just do:-

```
var record_id = $('#res_id').text();
```

If you are using multiple `#res_id`, then change them to classes `.res_id` and do:-

```
var record_id = $(this).children('.res_id').text();
```

`children` only travels a single level down.

Comment: Thanks! It worked correctly, in terms of my markup and usage of id, I set that to be the specific ID of an entity that shares the same class of the text associated with it. It may be wrong I suppose as I am fairly new to this